# Algorithm Help - Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Could use some help here if anyone has any ideas?

Develop the algorithm only

Use Theorem 7.2 to develop an algorithm for the recognition of equivalence relations on a finite set.

[image]

Comment: Did you even try something ?

Comment: FYI, we have tags which tell which areas of mathematics a question belongs to.  In this case, you chose the tags discrete-mathematics and algorithms.  So, there is no need to repeat these in the title.  The title can be about the specific problem.  How about "Algorithm for recognition of equivalence relation on finite sets" as a title.

Comment: Why did you just delete most of the question?

Comment: @user85542 Please don't delete the question you posted after users have answered it.

Comment: I've rolled back the destruction of the question to (what seems to be) the most recent legitimate version of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm is more than straightforward: Let a relation $R$ be given in form its $n\times n$ matrix $M$. Check if $I_n\le M$, $M=M^T$ and $M^2\le M$. If all are true, $R$ is an equivalence relation, otherwise it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, your algorithm needs to determine whether each and every condition $(a), (b), (c),$ is satisfied (and if so return isEquivalenceRelation = true) or if not (return isEquivalenceRelation = false).

Define $A$. Put $n = |A|$

Define a boolean method to determine whether each possible ordered pair $(a, b),\;a, b \in A$ is related ($a \sim b = 1$) or not $(a\sim b = 0)$.

Define a method to construct $M:= M_{n\times n} (\mathscr R)$

Define a method to return $M^T$: $n\times n$ matrix transpose of $M$.

Define a method to compute $M^2$.

Define boolean methods to evaluate, return $P \leq Q$, $P = Q$, each for input of matrices P, Q.

---

boolean isEquivalenceRelation = false;

- if $(I_n \leq M \;\;\&\;\; M = M^T \;\;\&\;\; M^2 \leq M)$

  - isEquivalenceRelation = true;

return isEquivalenceRelation;

---

As you see, most of the work in any potential program will occur with creating methods to do the computations of matrices needed and in comparing matrices. The actual "logic" involved in actually determining whether $\mathscr R$ is an equivalence relation on $A$ is pretty straightforward. So, depending on how "high level" of an algorithm you need, you may only need the loop.